# Angular2 / Firebase - better way to use Observables

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angular2-observables

I'm learning Angular2 and I am writing a Firebase based application, but I'm confused because of Observables.

When I check if the user is logged in (and if it is) I want to extract extra information from the database. But if they do not exist yet, create and then get them.

I already wrote the code and it seems to work fine. My questions is, what is the correct way to deal with it?

My code:

```
export class AuthService {
  user: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private auth: AngularFireAuth) {

    this.auth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.db.object('/users/' + user.uid).subscribe(info => {        
          if (info.uid) {
            this.user = info;
          } else {
            this.db.object('/users/' + user.uid).set({ uid: user.uid });
          }
        });
      } else {
        this.user = null;        
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i created a login with email and password

```
user: Observable<firebase.User>;
items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

 constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {

this.user = this.afAuth.authState;
this.items = db.list
```

}

```
loginEmail(email, password) {
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

}

Now you can check if the user is logged in or not

this.user has the authstate(boolean)

```
if (this.user){
this.item.push({users:,this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid})
```

[..]

Maybe this links are helping you

Firebase User[1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)

Example to use Observable to create a message board[2](http://talk-about-code.blogspot.de/2017/05/create-simple-messageboard-with.html)